# Google custom search auto complete not working

Tags: google-custom-search

I am implementing Google Custom search, I want auto complete in my custom search box, even though  I have  enabled auto complete from my control panel, it is still not showing up.
Please help me out with this.
thanks

Comment: Are you using version 1 or 2 of the code?

Comment: Even without any code or API, autocomplete already does not work in the standard public url that the CSE console provides, see my post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41374635/google-custom-search-autocomplete-not-working

Answer (score 1):

Here is limited [documentation](http://support.google.com/customsearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2631081) from google about this. Newly enabled or added autocompletions may take several hours to appear. In addition make sure that your site is being indexed by checking the settings under the Index tab.

Comment: Autocomplete does not even work after days or weeks, see my post here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41374635/google-custom-search-autocomplete-not-working. I think the product simply does not work as advertised or is really unstable, as long as no Google support shows me the opposite. You can already tell by all the dead links in the CSE documentation. Google product management at it's best, lol ;)

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have enableAutoComplete set to true in your  element